# Getting the index of a timestamp element in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, timestamp

I have a pandas data frame that I created as follows:

```
dates = pd.date_range('12-01-2020','12-10-2020')
my_df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns = ['Date'])
```

So this gives

```
        Date
0 2020-12-01
1 2020-12-02
2 2020-12-03
3 2020-12-04
4 2020-12-05
5 2020-12-06
6 2020-12-07
7 2020-12-08
8 2020-12-09
9 2020-12-10
```

My question is very elementary: What is the correct function to use for returning the index of a given date? I have tried `my_df['Date'].index('2020-12-05')`, expecting to get 4, but instead I got the following error: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable. I also tried

```
d = pd.TimeStamp('12-05-2020' + '00:00:00') 
my_df['Date'].index(d)
```

but I got the same error...I'm confused because I've used .index successfully in similar situations, such as on lists with integers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `query` without having to reset the index

```
my_df.query("Date == '2020-12-05'").index.values[0]
```

or if you want to assign the value to search:

```
d = pd.to_datetime('12-05-2020') 
my_df.query("Date == @d").index.values[0]
```

or without `loc` or `query`

```
my_df[my_df.Date == '12-05-2020'].index.values[0]
```

And your answer:

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But is there an alternate way that uses .index or .loc, but that doesn't involve resetting the index?

Comment: My answer doesn't reset the index

Comment: Thanks, I like the third option the best :)  It seems to me a more natural way of getting the index.

Comment: I do not think you need the `.values`, you can index directly into the index

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the index

```
my_df.reset_index().loc[my_df.Date == '2020-12-05', 'index']
```

or to get the scalar

```
my_df.reset_index().loc[my_df.Date == '2020-12-05', 'index'].values[0]
```

Comment: This seems very cumbersome...there must be an easier way that doesn't require reset_index...